# Laravel 8 upload and download file

Tags: laravel, datatable

I am trying to put a download button within a dataTable in Laravel but am getting the following error: "DataTables warning: table id=dataTableBuilder - Exception Message: Undefined variable: fileName".

This is my ReportController snippet:

```
public function store(CreateReportRequest $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'file_path' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:2048'
            ]);
    
        $report = new Report;
            if($request->file()) {
                $fileName           = time().'_'.$request->file_path->getClientOriginalName();
                $filePath           = $request->file('file_path')->storeAs('reports', $fileName, 'public');
                $report->name          = time().'_'.$request->file_path->getClientOriginalName();
                $report->file_path     = '/storage/' . $filePath;
                $report->save();
                Flash::success('Pop saved successfully.');
            }

        return redirect(route('reports.index'));
    }

    public function download($fileName)
    {
            $file_path = storage_path('reports') . "/" . $fileName;
            return Response::download($file_path);
    }
```

This is my view snippet (button for the download):

```
    <a href="{{ route('reports.download', $fileName) }}" class='btn btn-ghost-info'>
       <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
    </a>
```

And this is my routes snippet:

```
    Route::post('/reportdownload/{fileName}', [App\Http\Controllers\ReportController::class, 'download'])->name('reports.download');
```

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @KamleshPaul No it does not. I tried and am still getting the datatable error.

Comment: `<a href="{{ route('reports.download', $fileName) }}"` here from where `$fileName` it is coming .?

Comment: It is the name of the file that needs to be downloaded... I think?

Comment: Where do I define it?

Comment: in your `view` where you are using it

Answer (score 1):

try catching file with its {ID} in web.php and view as well
for example: WEB.PHP

```
Route::post('/reportdownload/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\ReportController::class, 'download'])->name('reports.download');
```

view:

```
<a href="{{ route('reports.download', $id) }}" class='btn btn-ghost-info'>
   <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
</a>
```